# Add new line using jQuery concat

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Through ajax response I'm passing  array data from controller to blade.

[image]

On Ajax success I'm looping through array with 2 elements and concatenating string to display later on in my bootstrap popover.

```
success: function (data) {
                var content = "";
                var num = 1;
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    content = content.concat(num + "." + " " + data[i]);
                    num++;
                }
                $("#content").popover({content: content});
            }
```

Result:

[image]

I would like to add new line, so that each item or "artikel" would be displayed in new line e.g. :

1.Artikel...
 2.Artikel...

I tried to add "\n" (as below) or html break but nothing works, it only appends as string.

```
content = content.concat(num + "." + " " + data[i] + "\n");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
content.concat(num + "." + " " + data[i] + "<br/>");
```

And this:

```
$("#content").popover({ html:true, content: content });
```